# How to read the 2 first chars of multiple files in cmd

Tags: batch-file

At work I need to create a .bat script that reads the first 2 chars on the first line, of multiple files, and then echo them to the screen.

So far I have this:

```
@echo off  
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion  
for /r I:\Test\Filer %%F in (*.*) do (  
set first2 =<%%F  
set first2=%first2:~0,2%  
echo %first2%  
)
```

But all it writes is: `ECHO is off`

Anyone got an idea what I have done wrong?

Comment: /p is missing in the SET line where you are reading the content of your file into the variable. I've posted the solution below.

Comment: I see it right now @MichaelS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing /p! This should work:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /r I:\Test\Filer %%F in (*.*) do (  
    SET /p first2=<%%F
    SET first2=!content:~0,2!
    ECHO !first2!
)
PAUSE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /r I:\Test\Filer %%F in (*.*) do (
set /p first2=<%%F
set "first2=!first2:~0,2!"
echo(!first2!
)
```

In `delayedexpansion` mode, `%var%` is the value of `var` at parse-time and `!var!` is the run-time value.

The `(` in the echo will ensure that a newline is shown if `var` is not set (or "set" to a zero-length string)

The quotes in a set statement ensure that trailing spaces are not included in the value assigned to the variable.

Note that spaces are not allowed after the variablename in a string "set" statement; a variable with a trailing space in its name will be set, and this is not the same as the variable with no space in its name.

`set /p` is required to assign a value from a file. Be carefu of zero-length files and files containing a newline (CR LF) at the start!

Comment: Now I just get: ~0,2 in the first line, and then ~0 for the rest.

Answer (score 0):

*Delayed Expansion* will cause variables to be expanded at execution time rather than at parse time, this option is turned on with the `SETLOCAL` command. When delayed expansion is in effect variables may be referenced using `!variable_name!` (in addition to the normal `%variable_name%` )

```
@echo off  
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion  
for /r I:\Test\Filer %%F in (*.*) do (  
set /p first2=<"%%~F"  
set "first2=!first2:~0,2!"  
echo !first2!  
)
```

Here in `set /p first2=<"%%~F"` use double quoted `"%%~F"`  (for a case if a path or file name contains e.g. space) and `~` modifier (to avoid doubling of double quotes)

Resources:

- [EnableDelayedExpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)
- [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) and their `~` modifier(s)